# convert all foreign string number to english number string

Tags: java, android

i want to convert string containing number in language other than English to English number Strings . 
for example  :
input :

> "۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹"

output :

> "123456789"

this is my code but still output is the same as input:

```
String text =  String.format(Locale.US ,"۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹");
```

Comment: This is definitely not how `String.format` works. You'll have to implement your own translator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Character.getNumericValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) to get the numeric value of a character; and then [`Character.forDigit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#forDigit(int,%20int)) to translate it to the latin number:

```
char[] ch = string.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; ++i) {
  if (Character.isDigit(ch[i])) {
    ch[i] = Character.forDigit(Character.getNumericValue(ch[i]), 10);
  }
}
String translated = new String(ch);
```

[<kbd>Ideone Demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/K5vE3N)

Comment: i tested it , the output is some odd characters

Comment: @ReZa I tested it on your input, in the Ideone Demo linked. The output is `123456789`.

Comment: @ReZa try it yourself!

Comment: i tested , it won't . also with your new edit i get this error : Error:(43, 53) java: no suitable method found for getNumericValue(char,int)

Comment: @ReZa try again now.

Answer (score 2):

For int code points (Chinese) too, java 8 style:

```
String s = "۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹";
int[] cps = s.codePoints()
        .map((cp) -> Character.isDigit(cp) ? '0' + Character.digit(cp, 10)  : cp)
        .toArray();
System.out.println(new String(cps, 0, cps.length));
```